# ListActivity with two lists

Tags: android, listview

I need to insert data from two list (populate from cursors) in the same activity.

The layout have to be:

-TextView1-
List from table1 cursor

-TextView2-
List from table2 cursor

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Use simple `Activity` with custom layout that has two `ListView`s.

Its easier then tweaking `ListActivity` doing something it was not designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. Just create a layout that contains both lists and initialize them in your activity as you normally would. If you use `ListActivity`, it will only handle one list for you. You'll need to do it the normal way for your second list.